# Reuse capturing group pattern in JS regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to test whether a string is 8 digits or the same number can be divided into 4 parts separated by a `-`.

I have a regex that does work:

```
/^\d{2}([-]?)(\d{2})\1\d{2}\1\d{2}$/
```

And I can prove:

```
/^\d{2}([-]?)(\d{2})\1\d{2}\1\d{2}$/.test('12345678'); // true
/^\d{2}([-]?)(\d{2})\1\d{2}\1\d{2}$/.test('12-34-56-78');  // true
/^\d{2}([-]?)(\d{2})\1\d{2}\1\d{2}$/.test('12-45-7810'); // false
/^\d{2}([-]?)(\d{2})\1\d{2}\1\d{2}$/.text('-12-45-78-10'); //false
```

I would have liked to have created a group from `\d{2}` but I tried this:

`/^(\d{2})([-]?)\1\2\1\2\1$/`

But it does not match anything.

Comment: It *does* match something: try "22-22-22-22".  By using `\1` it only matches the exact same two digits.

Comment: `\1` will match exactly the same text, not the variables. If you have `12121212` it will probably match it

Comment: Note that `^(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}|\d{8})$` works just fine

Comment: Things like `(?n)` / `\g<n>` (subroutines) are not supported in JS RegExp. See [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0w91h0x6/) to get a hint on how to get what you need.

Comment: Did [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50553431/3832970) help?

Answer (score 1):

You can write even shorter: `^\d\d(-\d\d){3}$|^\d{8}$`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make [*backrefernces*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) (references to actual values captured with  group patterns) work as [*subroutines*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html) (constructs "repeating" some group patterns, not the actual captured values).

You can only define pattern parts and use them to build longer patterns:

```js
const n = "\\d{2}";
const h = "-?";
const rx = new RegExp(`^${n}(?:${h}${n}){3}$`);
console.log(rx.source); // ^\d{2}(?:-?\d{2}){3}$
// ES5:
// var rx = new RegExp("^" + n + "(?:" + h + n+ "){3}$");
 
const strs = ['12345678', '12-34-56-78', '12-45-7810', '-12-45-78-10'];
for (let s of strs) {
 console.log(s, "=>", rx.test(s));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
const r = new RegExp(/^-?\d{2}-?\d{2}-?\d{2}-?\d{2}$/);
console.log(r.test("12345678")); // true
console.log(r.test("12-34-56-78")); // true
console.log(r.test("12-45-7810")); // true
console.log(r.test("-12-45-78-10")); // true
```

This works on my end.