# regex to check 2 IP address

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a requirement in which I have a range of 2 IP addresses.

```
192.168.1.1-192.168.1.1
```

I want to check that whether both side of dash are `valid` IP addresses. For single IP address I have a regex but I am not able to add a '-' for checking 2.

Need some help. Below is single IP regex.

```
^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$
```

Comment: Just add `-\1` at the end of your regex. `^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])-\1$`

Comment: @Toto That would require the *same* IP on both sides.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: I understand they want same IP address

Comment: Both IP can be different, but should be valid IP having a '-' between them, basically it will be a string of 2 IP with '-'

Comment: Then duplicate the same regex with an hyphen inbetween. `^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])-^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$$`

Comment: *I want to check that whether both side of dash are equal IP addresses.*  - the answer is really `^(pattern here)-\1$`. Please edit the question if it is not the real problem.

Comment: @Toto: and tomorrow's assignment will be to validate three of them... or ten ;)

Comment: @georg: May be, I just give here a solution for their specific problem.

Comment: Thanks everyone, you suggestions works,  looks like this is working ::     ^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])-(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$

Comment: Note you do not actually have to repeat the big pattern part, define it with a variable and build the regex dynamically, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50553431/3832970)

Comment: @georg, just asking on you comment, is it possible to have some generic solution in regex that take as many '-' between IPs

Comment: **See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50553431/3832970)**, that is an example of the generic solution. `^A(?:-A){0,Max-1}$`

Comment: @raju: glad you asked. In my opinion, regex is just the wrong tool for this job, because, as you can see, it's nothing but unreadable mess. What you can do instead is to write a short function that parses an IP into a number, and then compare these numbers anyway you want.